# Hiding images from android gallery

Tags: gallery, images

I dont want to install any 3rd party apps for hiding there images stored on device . How can I hide my images from the gallery app without installing any other app like Hide it Pro or Gallery lock? I use a low-end device and these apps use up my memory which would have otherwise been used for different apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'nomedia' file generally stored in whatsapp directory at  **Whatsapp/Profile Pictures**. If you dont have whatsapp installed, you will have to create a blank document and simply rename it to `.nomedia` this is simply an extension like `.txt`. Make sure that the name is only `.nomedia` and nothing else. The leading dot is important, too!